# Global Quaternion conversion to Local Quaternion

Tags: math, rotation, quaternions

I'm working with quaternions and I have a little problem.

I have an **object** (The violet line) and a **quaternion relative to the rotation axis** (Black line), and I want to **convert** this quaternion in **local space**, so that the **rotation axis become the object**.

I need to calculate the **roll of the object** (Which will be the Y rotation in local space that I will convert to axis angle) and then calculate the X and Z rotation in **Axis Angle**.

Here is a scheme that I drew to a better understanding of the question :

[image: Schema]

To understand you can think of your shoulder, when you move your arm you have the X and Z which will determine the forearm position and the Y which will determine the rotation of your elbow.

Do not hesitate to ask for clarifications, since it can be hard to understand what I'm searching for.

**Is there a formula or an algorithm that I can use to do so ?**

Is there 3D programmers who worked with quaternions and who can clarify me on the subject with an algorithm or just words?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a geometric formula, not programming.

Comment: Well It's actually a programming question since I need this for programmation purposes in a C# WPF application.

I'm a little lost because I can't find something on the web or anywhere..

Comment: Also I can put some code that I'm working on, but it's absolutely not what I want with the quaternion so I think that might be a little confusing

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/23414774/3088138

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's not a real answer but I think I can work with that

Comment: In the related topic I found something close to my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281864/translate-local-quaternion-rotation-into-global-gyro?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a quaternion q, such that qjq'=n, where n is the imaginary unit quaternion representing the axis of the object. This has a standard solution in terms of the product jn, essentially the square root.

If

```
jn=c+s*e, e imaginary unit, c²+s²=1, s>=0
```

then

```
q = sqrt(0.5*(1+c)) + sqrt(0.5*(1-c))*e
```

---

so compute

```
p=j*n // condition is n is imaginary unit
c=real(p)
e=imag(p)
s=abs(e)
if(s>0) e=e/s else e=j 
s=sqrt(0.5*(1-c))
c=sqrt(0.5*(1+c))
q=c+s*e
```

---

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23414774/3088138

Comment: I'll try to implement this, but I'm not sure to understand it all, what's the s and c part ?

Comment: what is j? is j the world's rotation axis?

Comment: It is the unit/basis quaternion associated to the y axis. As was said, the rotation axis is to be the y axis in local coordinates.